# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager

Tags: jsf, primefaces, web.xml, myfaces

I would like use Primefaces and Myfaces on my application. However there is an exception.

```
00:31:01,292 SEVERE [org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer] (http--0.0.0.0-8081-1) Could not load or parse web.xml: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager
    at org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager.newInstance(DTMManager.java:137) [xalan.jar:4.0.2 (build: CVSTag=JBoss_4_0_2 date=200505022023)]
    at org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.<init>(XPathContext.java:102) [xalan.jar:4.0.2 (build: CVSTag=JBoss_4_0_2 date=200505022023)]
    at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(XPathExpressionImpl.java:115)
    at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(XPathExpressionImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.initErrorPages(ConfigContainer.java:314) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.initConfigFromWebXml(ConfigContainer.java:291) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.<init>(ConfigContainer.java:88) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.context.DefaultApplicationContext.<init>(DefaultApplicationContext.java:35) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.context.DefaultRequestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultRequestContext.java:227) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.metadata.transformer.MetadataTransformerExecutor.processEvent(MetadataTransformerExecutor.java:50) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:43) [myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._traverseListenerList(ApplicationImpl.java:2471) [myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.access$000(ApplicationImpl.java:120) [myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl$SystemListenerEntry.publish(ApplicationImpl.java:2662) [myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:601) [myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase._publishPostAddToViewEvent(UIComponentBase.java:235) [myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setParent(UIComponentBase.java:215) [myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at javax.faces.component._ComponentFacetMap.setNewParent(_ComponentFacetMap.java:178) [myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at javax.faces.component._ComponentFacetMap.put(_ComponentFacetMap.java:145) [myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at javax.faces.component._ComponentFacetMap.put(_ComponentFacetMap.java:33) [myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._getComponentResources(UIViewRoot.java:623) [myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.addComponentResource(UIViewRoot.java:157) [myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper$1.processEvent(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:95) [tomahawk20-1.1.14.jar:1.1.14]
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:43) [myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._traverseListenerListWithCopy(ApplicationImpl.java:2517) [myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:594) [myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:616) [myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:222) [myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170) [myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117) [myfaces-bundle-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197) [myfaces-api-2.1.12.jar:2.1.12]
    at com.esilicon.web.jsf.FacesServletDecorator.service(FacesServletDecorator.java:62) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:294) [tomahawk20-1.1.14.jar:1.1.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.esilicon.web.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:27) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357) [tomahawk20-1.1.14.jar:1.1.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.esilicon.vms.web.admin.UserLoggedOffFilter.doFilter(UserLoggedOffFilter.java:40) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.

Comment: Please put the exception message into a code block to make it more readable.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. edited

Comment: please post the relevant code/configuration as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your webapp's runtime classpath is polluted with multiple different versioned JAXP libraries. In your specific case, the mentioned classes are loaded by different classloaders (one via server itself and other via webapp itself) and therefore couldn't be cast to each other.

Simply cleanup and remove the duplicate JAXP-related libraries in classpath (such as Xalan in your specific case). This covers among others the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and server's `/lib` folder. Do note that the average server already ships with JAXP out the box. So you do not need to provide those along your webapp at all.

This is not a JSF specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I removed xalan.jar from war file. However, this issue is still there. :(
Did I miss something?

Comment: Then there are more or the build is still dirty.

Comment: I also tried to remove xalan.jar from server's lib (inside modules folder in Jboss 7) but it caused java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/XPathAPI

Comment: I didn't know that there is xalan.jar on <JBoss Home>/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/xalan/main. I remove my own xalan.jar and use that one. Then the exception has been gone.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't have the need to touch the server. Your webapp is the one who shouldn't need to ship with a JAXP implementation in /WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Xalan came into the classpath via one of our dependencies, putting this in the "configurations" section of our main gradle file killed it off and fixed the problem immediately: all*.exclude group: 'xalan', module: 'xalan'

Answer (score 0):

In my case, JBoss already have xalan jar file inside module folder

```
<JBoss>/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/xalan/main
```

So i removed xalan jar file from my application lib folder and start with JBoss default one.
Its started successfully.

Answer (score -1):

When exposing web-service using Spring-WS, I got this exception. When the parameter 'transformWsdlLocations' is removed from MessageDispatcherServlet in web.xml. This issue got resolved.